# How can we create a treeview toolbox in blockly as in image any sample code or need guide to the docs

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

[In the image left is toolbox,when we select the option in tool box it opens a flyout in workspace as in the right can't understand the procedure in docs need help to integrate it using html javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDIED.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocky has provided the implementation method of treeView toolbox. Refer to this page:
https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/toolbox/index.html

After you implement the treeView toolbox, you just need to change the CSS style of each lable to achieve the desired effect.